# How to make the bot run a defined function at a specific time everyday in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, schedule

I want the bot to run a defined function everyday. I did some research and then I was able to write this:

```py
def job():
    print("task")
    
schedule.every().day.at("11:58").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

but this code is blocking all other functions so I did some more research from other stack overflow answers and then I was able to write this:

```py
def job():
    print('hi task')

def threaded(func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
    job_thread.start()

if __name__=="__main__":

    schedule.every().day.at("12:06").do(threaded,job)      
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
```

unfortunately this too , blocks my entire code. I need something that doesn't block other parts of my code. How to do that?

Comment: what about asyncio? You can create loop tasks with asyncio, check every 5 seconds if the current datetime is the right time and then do something

Comment: how to do that? can you please answer?

Comment: The documentation is your friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can able to loop a function in discord.py with

```
client.loop.create_task(function())
```

So with this, we can able to check time every second or 10-15sec.

```
import datetime
async def function():

    schedule_time = datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 3, 11, 58, 00, 000000)#(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    while not client.is_closed():
       now = datetime.datetime.now()
       if schedule_time  <= now:
           #JOB
           #add one day to schedule_time to repeat on next day
           schedule_time+= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
       await asyncio.sleep(20)

client.loop.create_task(function())
```

first set the date and time in `schedule_time` variable and in the while statement, it checks for every 20 seconds if the schedule_time met or passed the current time! if it does then it will execute the `#JOB` segment and after completing the job segment we should update the `schedule_time` variable to the next day! else it will be looped forever So, with the help of the [DateTime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module we updated the schedule_time variable with this line at the end!

```
schedule_time+= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set it up with asyncio

```
def job():
    print("task")
    
schedule.every().day.at("11:58").do(job)

async def task():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

**and also you shouldn't forget to add `client.loop.create_task(task())` on your on_ready event:**

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.loop.create_task(task())
```